# Iterating objects in a java program

Tags: iterator

Please note the logger info messages and the values of the Longs.
.getId() returns a Long value. 
procDefIdIn is defined as :

```
private static Long procDefIdIn = null;
```

procDefIdIn is passed to this class with a value of 131.
How does the last line of log info occur?
I also tried converting them to Strings using toString(). Same result.

```
private static void getDefinitions(List<DefinitionProcess> processes)
{
    Long procDefId = null;
    for (Iterator<DefinitionProcess> iterator = processes.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        DefinitionProcess proc = iterator.next();
        if(procDefIdIn != null){
            procDefId = procDefIdIn;

            logger.info(String.format("proc  = #%d procDefIdIn = #%d", proc.getId(), procDefIdIn));

            if(procDefIdIn != proc.getId()){ // How does 131 && 131 get past this?

                logger.info(String.format("Removed proc = #%d", proc.getId()));

                iterator.remove();

                continue;
            }
        }
        else{
            procDefId = proc.getId();
        }

          ........
          //Code here does not execute
         .......

    }
}
```

INFO  - proc  = #129 procDefIdIn = #131

INFO  -  Removed proc = #129

INFO  -  proc  = #130 procDefIdIn = #131

INFO  -  Removed proc = #130

INFO  -  proc  = #131 procDefIdIn = #131

INFO  - Removed proc = #131 //?!?!

Answer (score 3):

Please use

```
if(!procDefIdIn.equals(proc.getId())){
```

Comment: Use .equals() for non-primitive Object comparisons in Java, as this answer illustrates.

Comment: Long is not a primitive  Data Type

Comment: @Sebri Thanks for that and your careful edit after the post :). Yes, I keep forgetting things like that as I am transferring from C++ to Java.